# Is there a drawing library for ActionScript 3? (Pencil, Pen, Eraser tools, etc)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a drawing library for ActionScript 3? (Pencil, Pen, Eraser tools, etc)

I know that pencil and eraser probably aren't too complicated, but I don't want to roll my own pen tool if one exists.

Edit:
Looking along the lines of a vector system, that include the pen tool etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question closed - there doesn't appear to be a library that can handle this

Answer (score 1):

I found this at FlashAndMath http://www.flashandmath.com/advanced/smoothdraw/index.html.  They may have other code as well that can help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Graffiti](http://www.nocircleno.com/graffiti/) library.

Comment: So close to what I was looking for, but more looking along the lines of Pen tools (vector, etc) - should've mentioned that in the question, will edit now